# If $||x||^2||y||^2=|\langle x,y\rangle|^2$ then $||y||^2x=\langle x,y\rangle y$

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, inner-products

Let V be an inner product space with $x,y\in V$. Suppose $||x||^2||y||^2=|\langle x,y\rangle|^2$ . I want to show that the following holds

$$||y||^2x=\langle x,y\rangle y$$

I have that

$$||x||^2||y||^2x=|\langle x,y\rangle|^2x=\overline{\langle x, y\rangle}{\langle x, y\rangle}x$$

However this seems to put me in a loop.

I've tried to look at the properties of an inner product space, but it's doesn't seem to get me anywhere.

Comment: Do you know Cauchy-Schwarz inequality (and can you prove it) ?

Comment: So $||x||^2||y||^2=|\langle x,y\rangle|^2$ is equivalent to equality in CS, ie $y=c*x$. But then $||y||^2x=||c*x||^2x=|c|^2\langle x,x\rangle x$? However the $|...|$ seems to give me trouble?

Comment: @TJ123 Try going the other way. $\langle x,y\rangle y=\langle x,cx\rangle cx=\langle cx,cx\rangle x$.